# Why use linear combinations of random variables?

Tags: random-variable, covariance, linear, bivariate

I am in the process of learning about bivariate distributions, especially bivariate normal distributions. I have noticed extensive use of linear combinations of random variables where the goal is to generate a third variable, $Z$, based on two other variables, $X$ and $Y$, so that $Cov(Z, Y)=0$ in order to perform some analysis. What is the main reason for doing that? Is there any specific formula how to do that?

Comment: Linear combinations are extensively used in finance where a portfolio is being formed from a number of individual assets and, for example, a minimum-variance portfolio is sought after (but then the covariance is not zero; not sure when zero covariance is important).

Comment: @Richard Hardy E.g. when calculating $E(u|v)$ where $u$ and $v$ are jointly normal, dependent and with zero mean. As a result, a third variable is created and we are calculating $E(\rho\sigma_u\sigma_v^{-1} v| v)$.

Comment: @subhash c. davar Dependent events are those events in which probability $P$ of one events affects the probability of other event. There are many real life examples where two random variables are related - for example, the age of education and income and have joint probability distribution $F_{xy}$. Then, if we have two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ the joint probability distribution $F_{xy}$ would give the $F_{xy} (X=x, Y=y)=P(X\le x, Y\le y)$

Comment: @subhash c. davar In contrast to dependent events, two independents events would be rolling two dices - the first result doesn't not affect the probability of second result. However, if we consider the hypothetical example of age of education and income, we could say that is more likely that those with more age of education have higher income, as well.

Comment: let us talk about two random variables affecting each other and specifically  in the context of linear combinations.

Comment: @subhash c. davar Only the linear combination of two independent random variables having normal distribution will also result with a normal distribution.

Comment: what is "some analysis".

Comment: @subhash c. davar Statistical analysis.